# xargs + pv = messed up terminal

Tags: linux, xargs

if i want a little progress indicator on my long-running operation i can use [pipeviewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml):

```
ssh pc2 cat some.file | pv -nC reading | gzip --fast | pv zipping > some.file.gz
```

this gives me a fun little display telling me how fast things are going:

```
reading:  470MiB 0:00:18 [26.7MiB/s] [   <=>                              ]
zipping: 99.6MiB 0:00:18 [5.61MiB/s] [          <=>                       ]
```

but when i do a bunch of things in parallel, the output gets all messed up:

```
cat file.list | xargs -P 4 --replace={} sh -c "ssh pc2 cat {} | pv -nC r.{} | ..."
```

is there any way to make this work?

`man pv` says there's a way to circuitously pipe the output of `pv` into a utility called `dialog`, but i'm unfamiliar with that

Comment: Good question but off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 0):

You can execute each program instance in new terminal or in a dialogue box.  For terminal

```
cat file.list | xargs -P 4 --replace={} gnome-terminal -x sh -c "ssh pc2 cat {} | pv -nC r.{} | ..."
```

To view in dialogue box zenity

```
 cat file.list | xargs -P 4 --replace={} sh -c "ssh pc2 cat {} | pv -nC r.{} | zenity --text-info | ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel installed:

```
cat file.list | parallel --tmux -P 4 'ssh pc2 cat {} | pv -nC r.{} | ...'
```

This will start the jobs in `tmux`. You can then attach to `tmux`:

```
tmux attach
```

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your system, this should install it in 10 seconds:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

To learn more: Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
will love you for it.